# How come there seems to be less remote jobs where you can be trained in specific areas?

Tags: remote-work

I always noticed those kinds of jobs:

Company A seek people with certain skill-set (programmer, etc) and offer training for certain skills and such (for a specific amount of time, say 2 month) where they would *pay* you while being trained, and then decide to maybe increase your salary if you get out of the "training" process...

But the thing is, those are mostly done so by non-remote-work companies. Or at least, I never saw any company offering remote-work with possibility for training before actually working for them.

Is that actually a thing that's common or not (for remote-work)?

Comment: I haven't seen it either, seems very risky. I have seen remote where the training is provided by the company and product specific.

Comment: Yeah, i never saw it either which is why i got curious about it :) @Kilisi glad I'm not the only one to notice...

Comment: Probably because “sitting with Nellie” is not available remotely. For obvious reasons like you are in one location and Nellie is in another. Then multiple cameras my be needed to see all the actions in detail.

Comment: Welcome new user.  You mention software in particular. In general software is the epitome of **"learn it yourself and don't ask me"**. You're not going to find any "paid training" in software.

Comment: @Fattie I've given paid software training. And I know several people whose main source of income is to give software training.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Training is something a company offers when there is nobody available that already *has* the training or even experience with that sort of job.

Now when you sit in a medium sized town in the middle of nowhere, it might be a good idea to offer training, instead of waiting whether some random person with that skillset might decide to move to your town over the next years.

Once you look at remote positions, it is highly unlikely that you will not find that skillset *in the whole country* or even the world. Why offer training when you have people available that already have that training?

Comment: Good explanation. This has implications for the future now that WFH got much more widely accepted